# exclude a list of texts like

Tags: sql, postgresql

df

```
business_code business_category
A              Café / Restaurant
B              Car Repair Shop
C              Cleaning Services
D              Fast Food Restaurant
```

I would like to make exclusions if there are text similar to the text written.

```
select business_code, business_category
from schema.df
where vmdm.mcc_level not like('%Caf%', '%epair%', '%leaning%')
```

The code above does not work.

Expected output:
df_output

```
D              Fast Food Restaurant
```

Also, specifically for Cafe / Restaurant, how should I best exclude them both? If I write '%af%, it may exclude other business categories containing just those 2 letters.. If I write '%afé', 'Cafe' is not excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array and `ALL`

```sql
select business_code, business_category
from schema.df
where vmdm.mcc_level not like ALL(array['%Caf%', '%epair%', '%leaning%'])
```

If you were looking for inclusion, you would use `ANY`:

```sql
...
where vmdm.mcc_level like ANY(array['%Caf%', '%epair%', '%leaning%'])
```

Regarding the accent, you can have a look at the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) extension, or you can filter for both `cafe` and `café`.